# Dynamic url (with hash tags) for facebook like - FBML

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, hash, facebook-like, fbml

```
<script>
var fb_ps_page = window.location.href;
document.write('<fb:like href=" '+ fb_ps_page +'" send="false" layout="button_count" width="450" show_faces="false"></fb:like>');
</script>
```

The url is getting updating dynamically by ajax. So I thought I could use the above function, but I'm not sure that it works. (I'm in a dev environment).

Has anyone have any insight to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB.XFBML.parse() is your friend in this situation.